# NotFoundInDispatcherException on client JBoss after redeploying remote JBoss 5.1.0 application

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have the following setup:

```
Tomcat --WEB-SERVICE--> JBoss Proxy --EJB--> JBoss Back End
```

If I redeploy the application on the JBoss Back End without redeploying the code on the Proxy, subsequent invocations of the Back End's EJBs by the Proxy fail with the following errors in the log :

```
2012-05-11 08:40:31,907 ERROR [com.mycompany.ProxyImplI] (http-0.0.0.0-18880-2) Error method findUser null
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy360.findUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.ProxyImplI.findUser(ProxyImplI.java:622)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor307.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    ... snip ...
Caused by: org.jboss.aop.NotFoundInDispatcherException: Object with oid: jboss.j2ee:ear=backend.ear,jar=backend-internal-services-6.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=UserAccountsServiceImplI,service=EJB3 was not found in the Dispatcher
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:85)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:524)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:211)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy375.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at $Proxy360.findUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.ProxyImplI.findUser(ProxyImplI.java:622)
    ...snip...
```

Other useful bits of information :

- JBoss 5.1.0, running on non-standard ports*, a few unused services disabled, Metro Web Services 3.2.1 added
- Tomcat 6.0.14 (can't see this affecting anything really)
- JDK 1.6.0_18
- the bean being invoked is `@Stateless`

I'm pretty certain it should be possible to redeploy the backend without redeploying the proxy.

At the moment we get round it by redeploying the Proxy server, but we'd rather not have to do this.

Is there a way to invalidate the reference already in the `org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher` class, or is there another approach to take?

---

- I have seen [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-3724) bug which mentions a similar problem when using non-standard ports, but it's for JBoss 4.0.4.